# Getting user's default email address in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I obtain the user's default email address? I need to obtain it for my crash reporter dialog, so the user won't have to fill it out manually.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Never mind, I got it. First, I just have to add AddressBook.framework into my Linked Frameworks. Then, this is the code required:

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

NSString *theEmailAddressWeWantToObtain = @"";
ABPerson *aPerson = [[ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] me];
ABMultiValue *emails = [aPerson valueForProperty:kABEmailProperty];
if([emails count] > 0)
  theEmailAddressWeWantToObtain = [emails valueAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: You may want to use a combo box and populate its pop-up menu with all of the user's email addresses.

Comment: For iOS 6.1 Xcode doesn't like `ABPerson *aPerson = [[ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] me];`. The protocol must have changed drastically since 2011.

Comment: "me" is only a property on OS X, not iOS

Comment: Does that mean you can't get the users email on iOS?

Comment: terrible, to be able to autocomplete user's email we should ask for access to address book...

Answer (score 1):

From "**Address Book Programming Guide for iOS*":

> Link the Address Book UI and Address Book frameworks to your project.
>
> **Important** The project will fail to build (with a linker error) if you do not link against **both** of these framework.

Linking in the Framework without the UI will prevent the sample code from compiling.

Comment: The above poster is suggesting that in any project using the Address Book Framework, you should also include Address Book UI.