# How to retrieve 'self' from Address Book

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

I have noticed that in iOS 6 I have my own name with my number, email and etc on my address book. I dont know if this is new or for some reason some app added myself there...

Anyway is there a way to retrieve 'self' from the Address Book?

I have tried this solution but it didn't work:
[Getting user's default email address in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893099/getting-users-default-email-address-in-cocoa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API to do so on iOS 6 or earlier. If you want to see one, contact Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com to request it.

Comment: but what about this `[[ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] me]`?