# how to know if the IOS Mail App is configured to outlook or gmail

Tags: ios, email

Please let me know is it possible to know if the **IOS Mail App** is configured to outlook or gmail or etc via **code(Xcode)**?
If yes then please let me know how.

Let me know if you require more information.

Comment: It is not possible.  You can't snoop on another app's settings.

Comment: The best you can do if find their email address (if they've set it)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893099/getting-users-default-email-address-in-cocoa

Comment: @Marc the example to which you link will not work on iOS, only on OSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As borrrden said we cannot snoop on another app's settings.
So the answer is NO.